# startActivity(intent) it doesn't working ? when my DemoActivity use android:launchMode="singleTask",

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.ERPWebContainerActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.Eallcn.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

When I step into a new `Demo1Activity`, I deal with some data, Step to `Demo2activity` from `Demo1Activity`.
when I in the `Demo2activity` activity. I use this method:  `startActivity()` doesn't work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ERPWebContainerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("waitUploadImageLists", waitUploadImageLists);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Why did u add launchMode="singleTask"??

Comment: When you add code to your post, don't forget to use formatted code instead of pictures =)

Comment: Without launchMode attribute the code works as you expect ?

Comment: Why did u add launchMode="singleTask"??

Comment: I need this acitivity always in the alive, when the app is running!

Comment: @Virthuss   thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mat   i need the lunchMode!  It is useful for me!

Comment: I  try a method it is success:

Comment: I get the intent data form the  @Voerride  onNewIntent(Intent intent)   this callBack method help me reslove it!

Comment: @GeekHades: I was asking that only to debug the problem. Good anyway if you resolved

Comment: Have you seen in the logs, is there any exception in the logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can override this method, you can get the Intent data!
why ?  because the activity didn't finish, When i startActivity form Demo2activit, It does't go to onCreate method!

you can get the reslove way: you can see  Android: lunchMode

[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`which work almost same. 
but still if your requirement is to use `singleTask` only then you can use that in this way:

android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Just remove the `launchMode="singleTask"` and set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag whenever call an intent to your activity

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try in this order.

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(/*intent parameters, but as I can't copy and paste it from a picture then... */);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  but not this way!